# Android Spinner two-way binding with @InverseBindingAdapter / AttrChanged doesn't work

Tags: android, android-databinding

I've been trying for a while to set up a two-way binding on a Spinner.

There are many example of this on the web and here on stack overflow but none of them works for me.

It's just a country spinner, I've defined a country adapter for it with this methods:

```
@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "selectedCountry", event = "selectedCountryAttrChanged")
public static String bindCountryInverseAdapter(AppCompatSpinner pAppCompatSpinner) {
    Object selectedItem = pAppCompatSpinner.getSelectedItem();
    SpinnerAdapter adapter = pAppCompatSpinner.getAdapter();
    if (adapter instanceof CountrySpinnerAdapter) {
        return (String) selectedItem;
    }
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("The adapter must be a CountrySpinnerAdapter");
}

@BindingAdapter(value = "selectedCountryAttrChanged", requireAll = false)
public static void bindCountryChanged(AppCompatSpinner pAppCompatSpinner, final InverseBindingListener newTextAttrChanged) {
    AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener listener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            newTextAttrChanged.onChange();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            newTextAttrChanged.onChange();
        }
    };
    pAppCompatSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(listener);

}

@BindingAdapter("selectedCountry")
public static void bindCountryValue(AppCompatSpinner pAppCompatSpinner, String newSelectedValue) {
    SpinnerAdapter adapter = pAppCompatSpinner.getAdapter();
    if (adapter instanceof CountrySpinnerAdapter) {
        ((CountrySpinnerAdapter) adapter).bindSelectedValue(pAppCompatSpinner, newSelectedValue);
        return;
    }
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("The adapter must be a CountrySpinnerAdapter");
}
```

the `bindCountryChanged` method is never called.

I've also tried this variant (following other examples):

```
@BindingAdapter(value = {"selectedCountry", "selectedCountryAttrChanged"}, requireAll = false)
public static void bindCountryValueChanged(AppCompatSpinner pAppCompatSpinner, String newSelectedValue, final InverseBindingListener newTextAttrChanged) {
    AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener listener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            newTextAttrChanged.onChange();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            newTextAttrChanged.onChange();
        }
    };
    pAppCompatSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(listener);

}
```

This is called but `newTextAttrChanged` is always null.

The layout, binding part:

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="customer"
        type="my.package.CustomerBinding" />
</data>
```

And the widget:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
    android:id="@+id/editCountry"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    app:adapter="@{customer.countrySpinnerAdapter}"
    app:selectedCountry="@{customer.country}" />
```

`country` id just an `ObservableField<String>` and `countrySpinnerAdapter` is a `BaseAdapter` for the list of countries.

Android gradle plugin:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
```

Tools versions:

```
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
```

And of course data binding is enabled:

```
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```

Why `newTextAttrChanged` is always null / the BindingAdapter is never calld? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `app:selectedCountry="@{customer.country}"` aren't you missing a `=` for the two-way Binding, so it should be `app:selectedCountry="@={customer.country}"`...?

Comment: Jesus you are right! I somehow always overlooked it... Can you tell me the difference between `@={` and `@{`? I've always used the latter, when I'm supposed to use the `=` form?

Comment: I'll post an answer. ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are missing the `=` in the binding expression to notify the system that you would like to use this binding as a two-way binding.

```
app:selectedCountry="@{customer.country}"
```

should be

```
app:selectedCountry="@={customer.country}"
```

Comment: I'm not contesting your answer at all.. it is indeed correct but I really want to understand: the [official documentation][1] doesn't say anything about this. Nor [other] [2] articles about two way data binding. Is this needed for a regular ObservableField? This is the first time I tried two way data binding and puzzle me out :) probably starting with a custom field wasn't the smartest decision either

[1] https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html
[2] https://medium.com/@fabioCollini/android-data-binding-f9f9d3afc761#.xmm1v68hu

Comment: [This](https://medium.com/google-developers/android-data-binding-2-way-your-way-ccac20f6313#.ijqh87173) is an article from George Mount, the developer of the DataBinding library. You also should check out his other articles on medium :)

Comment: I'll do, thank you... I wish this kind of things was written in the official documentation tough...

Comment: now it is: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way